# Android database date type

Tags: android, date, sqlite

I am new starter android.
I have simple question. When I choose date through datePickerDialog and press confirm button, I want to store the date as date format instead of string.
How can I store the date format?

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = 
"create table fridge_table (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "+
"category text not null, name texct not null, expired_date text not null);";

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
  db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
}
```

How can I change expired_Date field? some of people said using long, or date.
I am wondering how to store in sqlite.

What I am trying to convert date, I want to set the alarm through this field.
Could you help me? and if you have any example, please give me some of example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Calendar object then.

You can save time like:

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
//set date,month,year,time etc. according to your need to cal object
//add expired_date's value as cal.getTimeInMillis()
```

You can also retrieve the same using:

```
long date=cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("expired_date"));
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
cal.clear();
cal.setTimeInMillis(date);
// you can use any format to display this time using String.format() method.
```

For various date format options,visit http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

**EDIT :**

For example:

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
String date_time=String.format("%1$te %1$tB %1$tY,%1$tI:%1$tM:%1$tS %1$Tp",cal);
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),date_time,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//this will show a toast containing current date and time in format "23 January 2010,12:30:15 pm"
```

Comment: That mean do I have to change String type to Long type first?

Comment: Not actually... you just need to change time/date in long.you can always convert it into human readable string using the formates in provided link in my answer. please see my edited answer.i am giving you an example there!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I am trying to do with your coding, but still doesn't work. I am trying to String date_format = String.format("%td-%tm-%tY", cal); instead of time. Is it right? original text was like, '24/11/2011'. Is it right format, and do I have to change '-' to '/'? when I try to this, I don't get it..

Comment: you need to use it like: String date_format = String.format("%td-%tm-%tY", cal,cal,cal); or String date_format = String.format("%1$td-%1$tm-%1$tY", cal);

Answer (score 3):

SQLite Version 3 only supports following datatypes so you cannot store date as a date type.
You should use the Calendar class of Java to do Text to Date conversions when retrieving and storing from the database

```
NULL. The value is a NULL value.
INTEGER. The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes 
    depending on the magnitude of the value.
REAL. The value is a floating point value, stored as an 8-byte IEEE floating
   point number.
TEXT. The value is a text string, stored using the database encoding (UTF-8,
   UTF-16BE or UTF-16LE).
BLOB. The value is a blob of data, stored exactly as it was input.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your Date from its format to the Long type, so you will have milliseconds in long data type. Then you can convert that milliseconds in Long to string and store as TEXT data type of Database.